# Missing user password in Parse log in

Tags: ios, parse-platform

Below is my code for phone number verification. First we query to check if user already exists; if so, I want to log in with that user. If not, I create a new PFUser.

```
- (IBAction)confirmButtonTapped:(id)sender
{
    // Check to see if a valid phone number is entered
    if ([self.phoneNumberTextField.text hasPrefix:@"+56"] && self.phoneNumberTextField.text.length == 12){
        self.phoneNumber = [self phoneNumberWithoutSpaces:self.phoneNumberTextField.text];

        // Check if phone number is already assigned to a Parse user
        PFQuery *phoneNumberQuery = [PFUser query];
        [phoneNumberQuery whereKey:@"phoneNumber" equalTo:self.phoneNumber];
        [phoneNumberQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error){
            if (!error){
                if (objects.count > 0){
                    // Move on to main tab bar and log in with user found
                    PFUser *user = [objects objectAtIndex:0];
                    [PFUser logInWithUsernameInBackground:user.username password:user.password block:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error){
                        if (!error){
                            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:@"recoverUser"];
                            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
                            NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:self.phoneNumber, @"phoneNumber", nil];
                            [PFCloud callFunctionInBackground:@"sendVerificationCode" withParameters:dict block:^(id object, NSError *error){
                                if (error){
                                    NSLog(@"Error calling cloud function: %@", error.localizedDescription);
                                }
                            }];
                            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"confirmNumberSegue" sender:self];
                        } else {
                            NSLog(@"Error logging in: %@", error.localizedDescription);
                            [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Connection Failed" message:@"Please try again." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
                        }
                    }];
                } else {
                    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:@"recoverUser"];
                    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

                    //Create new Parse user
                    [self createNewUser];
                }
            } else {
                NSLog(@"Error fetching user object: %@", error.localizedDescription);
                [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Connection Failed" message:@"Please try again." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
            }
        }];
    } else {
        [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Invalid Phone Number" message:@"Please enter a valid phone number." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
    }
}
```

I am getting a Parse error when trying to log in (Code: 201) Missing user password.

Comment: when you debug, can you see what's inside the object     objects? Check if the password is stroed or encrypted.

Comment: Inside of the PFUser object it shows 8 key/value pairs for serverData, none of which is the password.

Comment: After looking up the Parse SDK, I found out the password property in PFUser is meant only to be set and will not be filled with data from the server.

Comment: I understand, then, that the password might be stored in an object filled by the user? Otherwise you might want to make the login anonymous or store the password (if it is automatically generated) somewhere so you can always retrieve t.